# Calling webservice from oracle issue with arabic parameters

Tags: oracle, web-services, plsql, arabic

I am new in PL/SOL and I am trying to call a webservice from oracle that takes parameters ans send messages ... Actually it is working fine if I pass values in English, but for Arabic it's sending a message with question marks ???? . 
I tried to change my content type but nothing is working except:

UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=windows-1256');

with the same issue in Arabic.Can you give me a hint? Below is my code.

NB: If i pass parameters from .net client by calling the same webservice, messages are sent correctly in Arabic.
Thank you

```
PROCEDURE HIMS_SEND_SMS (username Varchar2 ,
                                password varchar2,
                                phone varchar2,
                                code varchar2,
                                message varchar2,
                                P_RESPONSE OUT VARCHAR2) AS

  l_param_list     VARCHAR2(512);
  l_http_request   UTL_HTTP.req;
  l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;
  l_response_text  VARCHAR2(32767);
  soap_request     VARCHAR2(1024);
  i integer;


BEGIN

 dbms_output.enable(100000);
 utl_http.set_transfer_timeout(300);


l_param_list := 'username='|| username ||chr(38)|| 'password='|| password ||chr(38)|| 'phone='|| phone ||chr(38)|| 'code='|| code ||chr(38)|| 'message='|| message;

l_http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request ('http://serviceexample.com/service.asmx/SendSMSHTTP'
                                          , 'POST'
                                          , 'HTTP/1.1');

  UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=windows-1256');

  --UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=windows-1256');

  --UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml; charset=ISO-8859-6');

  --UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml');

  --UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8');

  --UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=ASCII');

  UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Length', LENGTH(l_param_list));

  UTL_HTTP.write_text(l_http_request, l_param_list);

  l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);

  UTL_HTTP.read_text(l_http_response, l_response_text);

 -- l_response_text:= substr(l_response_text,92,1);

  P_RESPONSE := l_response_text;

  UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);

EXCEPTION

  WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body

    THEN UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);

END HIMS_SEND_SMS;
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked with Chinese characters, and I had the same problem. Setting the body charset to UTF-8 solved it. And, change the length to LENGTHB. Try this:

```
PROCEDURE HIMS_SEND_SMS (username Varchar2 ,
                                password varchar2,
                                phone varchar2,
                                code varchar2,
                                message varchar2,
                                P_RESPONSE OUT VARCHAR2) AS

  l_param_list     VARCHAR2(512);
  l_http_request   UTL_HTTP.req;
  l_http_response  UTL_HTTP.resp;
  l_response_text  VARCHAR2(32767);
  soap_request     VARCHAR2(1024);
  i integer;


BEGIN

 dbms_output.enable(100000);
 utl_http.set_transfer_timeout(300);


l_param_list := 'username='|| username ||chr(38)|| 'password='|| password ||chr(38)|| 'phone='|| phone ||chr(38)|| 'code='|| code ||chr(38)|| 'message='|| message;

l_http_request := UTL_HTTP.begin_request ('http://serviceexample.com/service.asmx/SendSMSHTTP'
                                          , 'POST'
                                          , 'HTTP/1.1');

  UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=windows-1256');

  --UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=windows-1256');

 --UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'application/soap+xml; charset=ISO-8859-6');

  --UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml');

  --UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8');

  --UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=ASCII');

  --Change to LENGTHB here
  UTL_HTTP.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Length', LENGTHB(l_param_list));

  --change charset:
  UTL_HTTP.set_body_charset(l_http_request, 'UTF-8');

  UTL_HTTP.write_text(l_http_request, l_param_list);

  l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.get_response(l_http_request);

  UTL_HTTP.read_text(l_http_response, l_response_text);

 -- l_response_text:= substr(l_response_text,92,1);

  P_RESPONSE := l_response_text;

  UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);

EXCEPTION

  WHEN UTL_HTTP.end_of_body

    THEN UTL_HTTP.end_response(l_http_response);

END HIMS_SEND_SMS;
```

More on this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch2charset.htm), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851717/pl-sql-utl-http-post-with-utf8-string-results-in-broken-characters)

Comment: Well I tried this solution, but I still have the same problem. It seems oracle itself is not accepting Arabic parameters. In other words, whenever I try to write arabic words, oracle is converting them to ???? before calling my webserice. Any idea about how to solve this problem?

Comment: @H.Al It is certainly not Oracle. It could be your database settings. Did you try to run the following query: `select value from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';` . What do you get?

Comment: I got this AR8MSWIN1256

Comment: @H.Al  'whenever I try to write arabic words, oracle is converting them to ????' where do you write them? do you store them in tables? what client are you using?

Comment: I am using oracle database 10g

Comment: Solved, after resolving my problem of commit i tried your solution but instead of using utf8 I used windows-1256 and it's working now, thank you @Hawk